# Python class adds empty line to last value

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Login Program in python. I'm trying to read and add the usernames, emails and passwords to a text file. When reading the file I'm using a class to create accounts using the usernames etc. and store them inside my users[] list so I can access it with something like "users[3].username".  Everything worked fine but I'm having one problem: When printing the last value of each account (in this case the password) there is an additional empty line. I dont want this because I cant use it like that for example when checking if a password is correct.

This is the code

```
class Accounts:
    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

users = []

def add_account(username, email, password):
    file = open("useraccounts.txt", "a")
    file.write(username + ", " + email + ", " + password + "\n")
    file.close()

def read_accounts():
    file = open("useraccounts.txt", "r")
    count = 0
    for line in file:
        count += 1

    file.seek(0)
    for i in range(count):
        x = file.readline()
        x = x.rsplit(", ")
        new_account = Accounts(x[0], x[1], x[2])
        users.append(new_account)
    file.close()

add_account("Banana", "banana@email.com", "1234")
read_accounts()
print(users[0].username)
print(users[0].email)
print(users[0].password)
print("Something")
```

This is what the Output looks like

```
Banana
banana@email.com
1234

Something
```

It also happens when dealing wiht multiple accounts and when writing the text file manually instead of using the add_account function. 
I'm sure the problem is my read_accounts function, because the problem does **not** occur when creating an account manually like this

```
account = Accounts("Banana", "banana@email.com", "1234")
```

Also since this is one my firsts programs let me know if you have any other tips.

1 More thing: Originally my post started with "Hey guys" but it got removed. Why does that happen lol?

Comment: ``file.readline()`` includes the line's newline character and you never remove it.

Comment: `new_account = Accounts(x[0], x[1], x[2].strip())` to strip the newline from the last part of the line;

Comment: Note that there is no point iterating ``for line in file: count += 1`` to count the lines, only then to iterate ``for i in range(count): ...`` to read each line. You already did so the first time, might as well use what was read.

Comment: As a side note, if you are going to use a file format that is almost CSV, you should use the `csv` module that will take care of that kind of problems and more.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I tried this before but it sayss `new_account = Accounts(x[0], x[1], x[2])
IndexError: list index out of range`. I'll definitely try csv in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.readline()` doesn't strip the newline character from the end of the line, so when you split it up, the newline is still attached to the last element (the password). So you should add an `rstrip()` to your reading, e.g.:

```
x = file.readline().rstrip()
```

This should help, happy coding!